# When sending a script call request, move Data Raw content to URL

Tags: elasticsearch

The simplest example:

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Rewrite without data raw Search URI:

```
GET /_search?from=0&size=10&q=user:kimchy
```

Is it possible to rewrite the example for Search Template like this:

```
GET /_search/template
{
    "id": "sample_id_script",
    "params": {
        "gte": "2020-10-15 00:00:00",
        "lte": "2020-10-15 23:59:59" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible via the [`source` query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string)!! You simply need to inline your JSON body and add the other `&source_content_type=application/json` query string parameter, and voilà!

```
GET /_search/template?source={"id": "sample_id_script","params": {"gte": "2020-10-15 00:00:00","lte": "2020-10-15 23:59:59"}}&source_content_type=application/json
```

Please note, though, that it's not the same concept as the example you're showing. In your example, we're hitting the `_search` endpoint and sending a query (i.e. using `q=`) expressed in the Lucene Expression language. It's basically the equivalent of what you would send in a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

The second case is different, because you're sending a search template via the `_search/template` endpoint. So even though the effect is the same (i.e. sending a payload via the query string), the concept semantic is different.